Joining time series numerical data to a shapefile - QGIS
I have a land use dataset that categorizes cover extension values by country. This dataset is a time series, so it has several entries by country according to measured years. Is it possible to apply this dataset as a layer or shapefile in which I can visualize the vegetation cover values per year?
The shapefile has a column with the same country codes and I have tried to join by this feature but since my data is a time series, the process compares country codes and selects only the first entry by country, ignoring all the entries below. I am trying to compare land cover by country and the evolution by year.


In QGIS, you can use the Join attributes by field value tool, and in the Join type, select "Create separate feature for each matching features (one-to-many)".

Then you will get a vector file, and there will be one country geometry for each year. In this case, it will be easy for you to filter years for visualization using the query builder (If you are planing to visualize your data in QGIS).


That worked fine. Thank you!
